# Hazelcast member without partitioned map storage, but with replicated map

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a cluster with few members, one of them is web application. I want to store partitioned maps data on all members except the web application, however replicated maps should be working on all members, including web application node.

I know that Lite Member is not holding any data and allows me to execute action on this member. However, I would like to keep ReplicatedMap entries on all nodes and that seems to be not possible in Lite Members.

So:

- M1: RM, PM1, PM2
- M2: RM, PM1, PM2
- LM1 - web application: RM

Where M1 - member 1, LM1 - lite member 1, RM - replicated map, PM - partitioned map

Is there any possibility to make such configuration in Hazelcast Enterprise 3.9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hazelcast uses the regular (non-lite) members for keeping the data for all data structures (it means that you cannot configure some members not to keep data for specific data structures), and lite members cannot be configured to keep any data. In summary, your request is not available for now.

If you don't want to keep partitioned maps' data on just one member (here LM1) because of your security concerns, you can use [Security Permissions](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#permissions) to prevent access to the data on some members.

Comment: Thank you :) Replicated Cache was considered as a type of broadcasating configuration

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a hazelcast client in the web application node and enabling [near cache](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.2/manual/html-single/#near-cache) on that client?

Comment: No, it was considered for broadcasting configuration only, but nice hint :)